# AJAX call answers appearing and disappearing

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax

I am writing an app using Jquery and ajax. The response is loading to the HTML and then disappearing.

HTML

```
 <figure class="card card--normal" id="firstResponse">
          <div class="card__image-container">
            <img id="#pokemon1Image" src="" alt="card" class="card__image">   
          </div>
          
          <figcaption class="card__caption">
            <h1 id="pokemon1Name"></h1>
        
       
              <h3 class="card__type" id="pokemon1Type"></h3>
          
        
            <table class="card__stats">
              <tbody><tr>
                <th>HP</th>
  
    <td id="Pokemon1Exp"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Attack</th>
                <td id='pokemon1Attack'></td>
              </tr>
              
              <tr>
                 <th>Defense</th>
                <td id="pokemon1Defense"></td>
              </tr>
        
              <tr>
                <th>Special Attack</th>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Special Defense</th>
 
    <td> <p id="pokemon1Defense"></p></td>
```

Response

```
.then(function (response) {
    var pokeID = response.id;
    var imageURL =


    $("#pokemon1Image").attr("src", imageURL);
    $("#pokemon1Name").html(nameOfPokemon);
    // $("#pokemon1Type").text(type + " type");
var attack =response.stats[1].base_stat
    // $("#pokemon1Attack").text(attack);
    // $("#pokemon1Defense").text(response.stats[2].base_stat);
    $("#pokemon1Speed").html(response.stats[5].base_stat);
    $("#pokemon1Exp").html(response.base_experience);
    $("#Ability").html(response.abilities.ability[0])
```

I feel like I've been doing this all day. Does anyone know why this is happening and can you help?

Thanks

Comment: The example code seems incomplete, for example `var imageURL = ` doesn't get assigned to any value. We could help you better if you can share a small example demonstrating what's going wrong for you.

Comment: ah oops no that's no it. I had cut and paste something because stackoverlow doesnt let you add a bunch of code. it's needed for this one though

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
$("#search-btn").on("click", function () {
  // event.preventDefault();
  var userInput = $("#input").val();

  var search = userInput.toLowerCase();
  $("#input").val("");
  // var pokemon = userInput.toLower
  pokemonOne(search);
 
  });

  function pokemonOne(search){
  var queryURL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + search;
 $.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET",

Comment: dataType: "json",

Comment: }).then(function (response) {
    var pokeID = response.id;
    var imageURL =
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/" +
      pokeID +
      ".png";
    var nameOfPokemon = response.name;

    $("#pokemon1Image").attr("src", imageURL);
    $("#pokemon1Name").html(nameOfPokemon);
    // $("#pokemon1Type").text(type + " type");

Comment: var attack =response.stats[1].base_stat
    // $("#pokemon1Attack").text(attack);
    // $("#pokemon1Defense").text(response.stats[2].base_stat);
    $("#pokemon1Speed").html(response.stats[5].base_stat);
    $("#pokemon1Exp").html(response.base_experience);
    $("#Ability").html(response.abilities.ability[0])

  
  })

}
})

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what problem you're facing given the code you've shared.
From what I can tell there is no reason for the result to disappear.
I did modify the code a bit to make sure that it functions like i would expect it to function.

The snippet below should load the pokemon.

```js
// define the search function. we will attach it to the button latter. 
function pokemonOne(search) {
  //build the url.
  var queryURL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + search;
  // execute the api call
  $.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
  }).then(function(response) {
    // process the api call
    var pokeID = response.id;
    var nameOfPokemon = response.name;
    $("#pokemon1Name").html(nameOfPokemon);
    // get the image url from the response. or build it yourself
    var imageURL = response.sprites.front_default
    //var imageURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/" + pokeID + ".png";

    $("#pokemon1Image").attr("src", imageURL);
    var attack = response.stats[1].base_stat
    $("#pokemon1Attack").text(attack);
  })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // attach hook to the search button
  $("#search-btn").on("click", function() {
    // capture the input
    var userInput = $("#input").val();
    var search = userInput.toLowerCase();
    // clear the input
    $("#input").val("");
    // execute the search function
    pokemonOne(search);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="input" value='arcanine' />
  <button id="search-btn">
    search
  </button>
</div>

<figure class="card card--normal" id="firstResponse">
  <div class="card__image-container">
    <img id="pokemon1Image" src="" alt="card" class="card__image">
  </div>

  <figcaption class="card__caption">
    <h1 id="pokemon1Name"></h1>
    <h3 class="card__type" id="pokemon1Type"></h3>
    <table class="card__stats">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Attack</th>
          <td id='pokemon1Attack'></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```